# In Star Trek Discovery, is it 3 hours warp from Pahvo to Starbase 46 or 12 hours?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, warp

In the Star Trek Discovery Episode [S1:E9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Into_the_Forest_I_Go_(episode)) *Into The Forest I Go* - Captain Lorca tells the Admiral they are three hours away by warp from [Starbase 46](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starbase_46). (They are leaving the [Pahvo System](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pahvo_system)).

Later, when leaving [Pahvo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pahvo) again, Lorca says they are 12 hours away from Starbase 46 by warp.

My question is: **In Star Trek Discovery, is it 3 hours warp from Pahvo to Starbase 46 or 12 hours?**

Comment: Depends on what Warp factor you use I guess.

Comment: If I remember correctly the first part was more of a combat type thus max. warp  while the other was a slow cruise.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: I reviewed the episode, and Lorca does not say that they are 12 hours away from Starbase 46, so the real answer is: 3 hours at warp 5, as stated on screen.